# Data masking in snowflake

Tags: user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, masking

How to create a SQL UDF in Snowflake to achieve this? I could able to achieve the same in JS

Need suggestions on Data masking in snowflake ?

Actual :
Customer John from Boston, calling to add newborn DOB 01/02/2015 to medical benefits. Update with following SSN 999-999-9999 etc.

Expected Output:
Customer xxxx from xxxxx calling to add newborn DOB xxxxxxxxx to medical benefits. Update with following xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx etc.

Comment: Hi - is the example (Actual) that you have given the contents of a field in your database? If it is then are all values in that field structured in exactly the same way i.e. no record has "Customer John Brown ..."? If not, then are you constructing this text string and if so, how?

Comment: Its Random text columns , it can have any format of text in any order . where I need to find the PII elemnts and mask them

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that, realistically, it is not possible to achieve what you want (obviously anything is possible if you throw enough time and resources at it).

The long answer...

You would need to be able to parse each text string, identify each word and, with 100% reliability, determine if it contained PII information and then mask it.

1. How would you identify people's names? You couldn't just use that fact that they are capitalised as whoever entered the data might have failed to do this. Also, all words at the beginning of a sentence would be capitalised
2. Even if you could recognise a "word" as a date, how would you know that it was a DoB (and therefore PII) rather than some other date?
3. You might have a date like "1st January 2020" - how would you recognise this as a date as parsing the individual words won't work?

I don't believe even commercially available data governance solutions (of which I have some experience) would be able to do this reliably. They almost always work on columns of data and look at the whole column's contents to see if it might be a PII candidate (often with some pretty sophisticated AI/ML going on) - I've never seen a solution that could parse a long text string and could extract individual PII elements from it (though if anyone does know of such a solution I'd be interested to hear about it).

Comment: Thanks for your comment NickW. I could able to find most of the data patterns by re-hydrating the REGEX. I accept the challenges that you mentioned above. Finding the solution for those :) :(